# Mimic Timeout Exception in RabbitMQ, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Background:
Our application is a multi-threaded .NET based application. Each thread would connect to the same exchange and corresponds to different queue. Each thread uses a  long living connection of its own, everything was going fine until one day we got timeout exceptions on all the threads, and our application crashed. I assume its a server side issue and few of the sites too mentioned it could be due to Garbage collection or memory constraints. 
Solution: RabbitmQ recommends to use NetworkRecoveryInterval option for timeout issues.

**I need help in mimicking this scenario and ensure that the fix works.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You state: "I assume its a server side issue and few of the sites too mentioned it could be due to Garbage collection or memory constraints." Why would you assume that? Do you have evidence to back that claim up? You don't mention important information like what version of RabbitMQ and Erlang you're using, or if you found anything interesting in the RabbitMQ logs.

Comment: @LukeBakken unfortunately we do not have server logs all we have is application logs which gives us the following information:


RabbitMQ-EXCEPTION processing Worker thread message:
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at RabbitMQ.Util.BlockingCell.GetValue(TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicGet(String queue, Boolean autoAck)

 The versions are : RabbitMQ 3.6.12, Erlang 19.3.2

Comment: Every operation has a timeout by default, I believe. Search the code for `ContinuationTimeout` - you should be able to extend that. I think `BasicGet` can timeout if there are no messages in the queue to consume.

Comment: @LukeBakken i tried to simulate with no messages in the queue but was of no luck,

Answer (score 0):

The [`toxiproxy`](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy#toxics) application can do what you need.